# Using timestamp as mongodb _id?

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I want to use MongoDB to store timeseries data, and think it would make things more sense to keep one unique indexed field that represent date-time. So the question is, can I really replace the automatic `_id` creation with my own timestamp, and would there be any drawbacks?

Comment: what's your timeseries frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I really replace the automatic _id creation with my own timestamp?

Yes, you can.

> would there be any drawbacks?

One is that you have to work for it, whereas the built in _id is, well, built in.
Another one is that you're responsible to making sure your _id is indeed unique.  Depending on your data frequency and the kind of timestamp you use, this may or may not be simple.

I'm not saying it's necessarily a bad idea.  The advantages are clear, but, yes, there are drawbacks.

Comment: kool, is there anyway I can make mongo reject any insert that doesn't have _id field (or not a valid timestamp, whatever that maybe?)

Comment: @xcorat - many of the MongoDB drivers automatically populate the field if it is empty. Some drivers, like the C# driver, have a way of plugging in a generator or checker for [example](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#selecting-an-idgenerator-to-use-for-an-id-field-or-property)

Comment: That's nice, maybe I can look into pymongo code since I'm using python. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely populate `_id` field with your own timestamp. The things to look out for are:

1. `_id` is a unique index so you would have to be sure that no 2 documents shared a timestamp. If you can't guarantee this then it would not work.
2. If you were to shard this collection, you may want to avoid using a timestamp as the shard key. If you were always writing data points with the current timestamp then you would find all of your writes would go to a single shard, rather than distributed evenly across shards.

Comment: thx. unique ID is not a problem, I can just use upsert to insert more fields. for sharding, wouldn't auto generated _id have the same problem then? it's using sort of a timestamp too right?

Comment: yes, autogenerated _id would have the same problem. in 2.4 you can use hashed index on _id as the shard key to avoid the uneven distribution problem.